# Display online users as soon as they log in

Tags: php, ajax

I could make an AJAX request that displays the online users for each user. The request is done every 5-10 sec. or whatever. The problem is, isn't that overloading my server too much? Is there a way to do it that it will update the online users for everyone else instantly?

Comment: If you have say 50 or 100 concurrent users, this will most likely not be a problem. However, if you have more you should look into longpolling, websockets or similar - here is some inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a system that can be used to indicate "Presence" events (Join/Leave/Is Typing/Geo/Lat/Long/etc) in real-time, you should check out PubNub:

http://www.pubnub.com/

Of specific interest to you would be the publish, subscribe, presence, and state APIs.

Both PHP and JS client SDKs are available:

https://github.com/pubnub/php
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/javascript-sdk.html

geremy

Comment: I was thinking I could write my own algorithm to do it.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc you certainly can. But its another thing to write and maintain. Services like PubNub have written it already server-side and client-side, officially support it, and provide global HA/Failover, with geo-sensing to send users to the datacenter quickest to them. Its not trivial, but definitely possible to write your own.